# Alert isn't presenting when we use confirmationDialog in a View Xcode 13

Tags: swiftui, ios15, xcode13

```
struct ConfirmationDialog: View {
    @State private var showingOptions = false
    @State private var showingAlert = false

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button("Show Options") {
                showingOptions = true
            }
            .alert("Alert Title", isPresented: $showingAlert, actions: {
                Button {
                    // Do nothing
                } label: {
                    Text("Okay")
                }
            }, message: {
                Text("Alert Message")
            })
            .confirmationDialog("Select option", isPresented: $showingOptions, titleVisibility: .visible) {
                Button("Show Alert") {
                    self.showingAlert = true
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Alert isn't presenting when I use confirmationDialog and alert in a single View.

I'm getting a console log when confirmationDialog is presented for first time.

**Attempting to present an alert while a confirmation dialog is already presented. This is not supported.**

I'm using XCode 13 and iOS 15 simulator

Is it a bug in XCode 13?

Comment: Have you tried to change the sequence ?

Comment: @RajaKishan Yes, changing the sequence is also not working.

Comment: @SrikanthThangavel this is fixed in XCode 13.2 Beta and iOS 15.2. Using your code snippet above is not producing the given console log

Comment: Glad, someone actually can confirm this bug ;)  @Carsten

Comment: Tried in XCode 14.2 and iOS 16.2 and working fine.